# XAML List<LineSeries> binding to chart Series

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, charts, toolkit

I have MVVM silverlight app with toolkit charts.
In view model I created ObservableCollection property:

```
    private ObservableCollection<LineSeries> _lines = new ObservableCollection<LineSeries>();
    public ObservableCollection<LineSeries> Lines
    {
        get { return _lines; }
        set
        {
            _lines = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Lines");
        }
    }
```

Then in some method I populate this collection with dynamic count lines:

```
            List<SolidColorBrush> colors = BS2ColorSetHelper.GetSetColors();
            for (int i = 0; i < remainderData.Count; i++)
            {
                LineSeries line = (colors.ElementAtOrDefault(i) != null)
                    ? CreateNewLineSeriesWithColor(remainderData[i].DenominationName, remainderData[i].Coords, colors[i])
                    : CreateNewLineSeries(remainderData[i].DenominationName, remainderData[i].Coords);

                line.Name = remainderData[i].DenominationName;
                Lines.Add(line);
            }
            .........
```

Now I want to bind this ObservableCollection to toolkit chart series.

```
    <toolkit:Chart Name="chart">
        <toolkit:Chart.Series>
            ????
        </toolkit:Chart.Series>
    </toolkit:Chart>
```

I have tried

**Series="{Binding Path=Lines}"**

but it doesn't work. Visual Studio shows an error: Object of type 'System.Windows.Data.Binding' cannot be converted to type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[System.Windows.Controls.DataVisuali‌​zation.Charting.ISeries]'. I think it's because Series are not dependency property.

Comment: depends on the property that is used in the control `Chart` you probably have to look at the documentation from the control maker

Answer (score 1):

Ok, we can't bind LineSeries to Series because Series are not Dependency property.
So we can create new UserControl with this dependency properties:

```
public class MultiChart : Chart
{
    public IEnumerable SeriesSource
    {
        get
        {
            return (IEnumerable)GetValue(SeriesSourceProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(SeriesSourceProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SeriesSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        name: "SeriesSource",
        propertyType: typeof(IEnumerable),
        ownerType: typeof(MultiChart),
        typeMetadata: new PropertyMetadata(
            defaultValue: default(IEnumerable),
            propertyChangedCallback: new PropertyChangedCallback(OnSeriesSourceChanged)
        )
    );

    private static void OnSeriesSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        IEnumerable newValue = (IEnumerable)e.NewValue;
        MultiChart source = (MultiChart)d;

        source.Series.Clear();

        foreach (LineSeries item in newValue)
        {
            source.Series.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Then we just bind LineSeries to newly created property:

```
    <common:MultiChart Name="chart"
                       Title="{Binding Path=Title}"
                       SeriesSource="{Binding Path=Lines}" />
```

The View Model will be:

```
public class ChartDenominationViewModel : ViewModel
{
    private string _title;

    public string Title
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set
        {
            _title = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Title");
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<LineSeries> _lines = new ObservableCollection<LineSeries>();

    public ObservableCollection<LineSeries> Lines
    {
        get { return _lines; }
        set
        {
            _lines = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Lines");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know fully the information about the control `Chart` I would suggest you check the documentation provided by the control originator to find out the name of the bindable property.

But from what you post my guess would be to try:

```
<toolkit:Chart Name="chart" Series={Binding Lines}/>
```

guessing that your Datacontext is all in place. meaning the datacontext of the page is set to your viewmodel

Comment: I have tried, but it doesn't work.
Visual Studio shows an error:
Object of type 'System.Windows.Data.Binding' cannot be converted to type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.ISeries]'.
I think it's because Series are not dependency property.

Comment: You will have to read the documentation from the `toolkit` you are using to find out the name of the dependency object to bind to